# "Class" attribute doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a search field with a drop-down which contains what data I'm looking for, the input type depends on what I'm searching.
If I'm searching by "name" or "ID number", the input type is `text`.
If I'm searching by "Employment date", "TOR Date" or "Expired Date", the input type is `date`.

I use `createAttribute` and `setAttributeNode` to set `class` attribute to each value, I also use bootstrap datepicker that only shows Month and Year (I've included the .js and .css file in my folder). Here's my code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="search_by" id="search_by" onchange="changeForm()">   
            <option value="idnum">ID Number</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="emp_date">Employment Date</option>
            <option value="amel_date">AMEL Expired Date</option>
            <option value="tor_date">TOR Expired Date</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group input-append date" data-date-format="mm-yyyy">
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search_keywd"/>
    </div>

    <script>
        function changeForm()
        {
            var form = document.getElementById("search_keywd");
            var x = document.getElementById("search_by").value;
            var att = document.createAttribute("class");
            if(x == "emp_date")
            {
                att.value = "form-control datepicker";
            }
            else if (x == "amel_date")
            {
                att.value = "form-control datepicker";
            }
            else if (x == "tor_date")
            {
                att.value = "form-control datepicker";
            }
            else if (x == "name")
            {
                att.value = "form-control";
            }
            else if (x == "idnum")
            {
                att.value = "form-control";
            }
            form.setAttributeNode(att);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Current Attribute: " + att.value;
        }
        $(document).ready(function (){
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
          format: "mm/yyyy",
          viewMode: "months",
          minViewMode: "months"
        });
    });
    </script>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

The problem is the datepicker doesn't show up, but the `if` logic works fine. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Where is your input element with 'datepicker' css class?

Comment: The "datepicker" class is only for "Expired Date" or "Employment Date". I use `if` logic to determine that. The `if` logic works just fine as shown by `.innerHTML`. But the datepicker still doesn't show up although the `att.value` has changed.

Comment: @W.Mustikarini I have shared a demo. Please link the datepicker to the script and test the same.

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 the code doesn't show bootstrap datepicker, but it only shows basic html datepicker. It's like when I use `type="date"`.

Comment: Why `createAttribute("class")` ?? [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) isn't good enough for you?

Comment: @W.Mustikarini You need to link datepicker library to the markup. Since you didn't added the same (library) in your question, I haven't done the same in my question. Also, your original problem of class adding not working is solved here.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I used that to assign `type` attribute before but I can't modify the datepicker to only show months and years, so I changed it to `class` attribute and modify the datepicker using css.

Comment: That's is not how it works with DatePicker. You have to instanciate it with **options**. --- Is that [**the one**](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) you are using?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette no, I use [bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Comment: The options you have seem correct... But we don't see the element with `datepicker` class in the markup you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You were creating the attribute for `document` instead of the `input`.

Use `[classList][1]` directly instead

```
 function changeForm()
    {
        var form = document.getElementById("search_keywd");
        var searchBy = document.getElementById("search_by");
        var x = searchBy.value;
        var classList = form.classList;
        form.className = "";
        switch( x ) //use switch instead
        {
            case "emp_date":
            case "amel_date":
            case "tor_date":
               classList.add( "datepicker" );
            case "name":
            case "idnum":
               classList.add( "form-control" );
               break;
            default:
               break;
        }

        //rest of the code
    }
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "mm/yyyy",
    viewMode: "months",
    minViewMode: "months"
  });
});

function changeForm() {
  var form = document.getElementById("search_keywd");
  var searchBy = document.getElementById("search_by");
  var x = searchBy.value;
  form.className = "";
  var classList = form.classList;
  switch (x) //use switch instead
  {
    case "emp_date":
    case "amel_date":
    case "tor_date":
      classList.add("datepicker");
    case "name":
    case "idnum":
      classList.add("form-control");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Current Attribute: " + classList;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" name="search_by" id="search_by" onchange="changeForm()">   
            <option value="idnum">ID Number</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="emp_date">Employment Date</option>
            <option value="amel_date">AMEL Expired Date</option>
            <option value="tor_date">TOR Expired Date</option>
        </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group input-append date" data-date-format="mm-yyyy">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search_keywd" />
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Shouldn't we also be removing the others before adding the class mapping to the current selected value ?

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan You are right. I have made the change.